# Why @ComponentScan is required while adding @SpringBootApplication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to SprinBoot and I have written a simple application which is having
a controller class. But when I tried to hit that controller from browser it was giving
HTTP-404 error. It started working only after adding `@ComponentScan` annotation to load that controller.

My question is, even though I am using `@SpringBootApplication`, why do I need to add `@ComponentScan` annotation?
Isn't it supposed to do the same thing ?

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.springboottest</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBoot Test App</name>
    <description>SpringBoot Test App</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**Controller :**

```
package com.test.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/sayHello")
    public String testRequest() {
        return "hello";  
    }
    }
```

**Main Method :**

```
package com.test.springboottest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan("com.test.controller")
    public class TestSpringBootApp {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(TestSpringBootApp.class, args);
            String[] defnName = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            int i =0;
            while(i<defnName.length) {
                System.out.println(defnName[i]);
                ++i;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Side note: you realise that Spring Boot 1.4.2 is an exceptionally old version of Spring Boot, I hope?

Comment: does your main method is under com.test package? or in which package is your main method ?

Comment: @SantosshKumhar Updated import and package statement in my question

Comment: then your controller should be in com.test.springboottest.controller package or your base package where your main method is should be com.test

Comment: @SantosshKumhar Understood

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `@ComponentScan` annotation is not required if the `TestSpringBootApp` is located in the *root package* of your application, which, in this case, seems to be `com.test`.

Refer to the Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class) for details:

> We generally recommend that you locate your main application class in a root package above other classes. The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is often placed on your main class, and it implicitly defines a base “search package” for certain items.

The documentation also provides an example:

> The following listing shows a typical layout:
>
> ```
> com
>  +- example
>      +- myapplication
>          +- Application.java
>          |
>          +- customer
>          |   +- Customer.java
>          |   +- CustomerController.java
>          |   +- CustomerService.java
>          |   +- CustomerRepository.java
>          |
>          +- order
>              +- Order.java
>              +- OrderController.java
>              +- OrderService.java
>              +- OrderRepository.java
> ```